# sshfs with fstab: connection reset by peer

Tags: fstab, sshfs

I am trying to allow my laptop (Ubuntu 13.04) to access my PC (Lubuntu 13.04) hard drive through SSHFS. I'm using RSA keys to connect.

It works perfectly fine if I type this in the terminal:

```
sshfs my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder
```

But I would like it to be mounted automatically when I boot my laptop. So I added myself to the fuse group:

```
sudo adduser mynickname fuse
```

And I added the following line to my fstab file:

```
sshfs#mynickname@my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder fuse defaults,idmap=user,_netdev 0 0
```

When I boot the laptop, a_folder appears in the list of devices, but is not mounted. When I try to access it through Nautilus, it displays the following error:

```
mount: only root can mount sshfs#mynickname@my-PC:/a_folder on /media/a_folder
```

I get the same error if I try

```
mount /media/a_folder
```

in a terminal.

If I try

```
sudo mount /media/a_folder
```

I get

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried to add "allow_other" as an option in the fstab entry, and uncommented the related line in /etc/fuse.conf, but it didn't change anything.

The user "mynickname" is the owner of the folder /media/a_folder and has rwx permissions.

I looked at many threads on the internet about people with quite similar issues, but nothing worked so far. Usually, people can't even do

```
sshfs my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder
```

without getting an error, whereas this works fine on my laptop.

Any insight and tips will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: I solved this issue a while ago, but I forgot to update this post. So here is what is in my fstab:

```
sshfs#mynickname@my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder fuse noauto,_netdev,idmap=user,user,default_permissions 0 0
```

The key option to add was default_permissions if I recall. I had to add mynickname to the group to which belongs /a_folder/ on my-PC.

Answer (score 9):

The problem you are experiencing is that your normal user has a correct setup for your identity file, while the root user has no idea what ssh key to use.

You can fix this by telling fstab what identity file/ssh key to use while trying to connect:

```
sshfs#user@host:/mnt/whatever/ /mnt/whatever/        fuse    user,_netdev,reconnect,uid=1000,gid=1000,IdentityFile=/home/USER/.ssh/KEYFILE,idmap=user,allow_other  0   2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried with the IdentityFile option, but I didn't specify the uid and gid options, so I will try that!

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't need to use `sudo` if everything is set up correctly for a FUSE mount.  Also, the uid/gid settings should only affect which user has rights to the files on your system.

Comment: So I just tried with uid, gid, IdentityFile, allow_other, all those options at the same time, and unfortunately it still doesn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample of how you've gotten it written?  You should be pointing to your private key, and **not** your public key.

Comment: You also must put your user in the **fuse** group and restart your machine in order for the *allow_other* to work.

Comment: Yes, I am pointing to my private key, and I already am in the fuse group (I used the command: `sudo adduser mynickname fuse`). Here is the exact line I have in fstab:

`sshfs#mynickname@my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder fuse defaults,idmap=user,_netdev,IdentityKey=/home/mynickname/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other 0 0`

Comment: Is *my-PC* an IP Address, or something you've set up in your normal user's **~/.ssh/config** file?

Comment: It is not an IP. It is the name of my PC, which is set up in the file /etc/hosts. I do not have a config file in ~/.ssh/. I do however have a known_hosts file in ~/.ssh/. Can that cause this issue? Should I try to use my PC's IP in fstab, or should I set up a config file? I'll try both in the meantime.

Thanks!

Comment: So both methods didn't work. Still the same error. For the config file, I tried by specifying for the right host: user, hostname (tried both IP and name), identityfile. But it didn't work as well.

So what I end up doing for now is that I added the command
    sshfs my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder
in the startup applications. It's not as clean as using fstab, but it works well enough for now.

Thanks for your help and your suggestions! If you think of something else, feel free to share, I'll appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

To get real debug output you need to add both `sshfs_debug` and `debug` options to the mount:

```
sshfs#mynickname@my-PC:/a_folder /media/a_folder fuse defaults,idmap=user,_netdev,debug,sshfs_debug 0 0
```

With this you will get a lot of debug info to help you:

```
$ sudo mount -a
SSHFS version 2.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.2
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-2> <user@box> <-s> <sftp>
user@box's password: 
Server version: 3
Extension: posix-rename@openssh.com <1>
Extension: statvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: fstatvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: hardlink@openssh.com <1>
Extension: fsync@openssh.com <1>
unique: 1, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56, pid: 0
INIT: 7.22
flags=0x0000f7fb
max_readahead=0x00020000
remote_uid = 1001
   INIT: 7.19
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00020000
   max_write=0x00020000
   max_background=0
   congestion_threshold=0
   unique: 1, success, outsize: 40
unique: 2, opcode: STATFS (17), nodeid: 1, insize: 40, pid: 2771
unique: 3, opcode: LOOKUP (1), nodeid: 1, insize: 47, pid: 3371
```

In my case I discovered that my machine was only listed in `.ssh/config`, so it was unresolvable for root.

And BTW, you need to set uid and gid, since `idmap=user` only seems to work for the current user, which is root in this case.

Comment: The `sshfs_debug` and `debug` helped me.  Turns out it was using the wrong port because fstab wasn't using the user `~/.ssh/config` file.  I also had to answer `yes` to accept the new host for that key.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can also occur when the host key of ssh changes.

Try to connect to the server via ssh (e.g. `ssh username@hostIP`). If the following error appears:

```
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!    @
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Follow the instructions in the error message to delete the old key and try to connect again via ssh. If the error does not appear any more, the sshfs connection should work.

Comment: "try to connect to the server via ssh" Make sure to do this *as root* if you're mounting the directory as root (which is what happens when automounting). A user's `known_hosts` file can be different from root's `known_hosts` file.

Answer (score -1):

Full disclosure: old-school geek, but brand spanking new to the linux/open source world

First off, I'm still using password authentication because I haven't yet become savvy enough with RSA keys. That's nearing the top of the list though.

Relevant set-up info:
Using a MacBook Pro with VMWare Fusion installed, on which I have Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS. Relying on Mac's terminal and SSH for almost all my server interaction

After botching a Drupal install, I rolled back to a prior snapshot and was suddenly unable to execute a command that I had just used moments previously: `sshfs -o idmap=user -o allow_other user@mac.home:/Users/<username>/Documents ~/mountpoint`

The issue is that the keys got out of sync. I don't know if I actually needed to do this on both my host and server, but  I cleared out all of the local keys on each by first making a back-up of the known_hosts file, then editing the known_hosts file to remove entries.
On Mac, this file was located at: `/Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts`
On Ubuntu, this file is located at: `/home/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts`

So, to summarize, all performed from my Mac terminal, after starting up Ubuntu server:

```
cp /Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts /Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts.old
nano  /Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts
  # remove extra entries, save file
ssh <username>@ubuntu_server
cp /home/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts, /home/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts.old
nano /home/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts
  # remove extra entries, save file
```

Upon first SSH into each system, SSH prompts me to allow RSA keys to be added and all works thereafter.